# Creating an exception for needing admin credentials to install software

Tags: user-permissions, webex

An employee at my company uses the service WebEx on a regular basis, and every time someone uses the service, they have to temporarily install their plugin in order for it to work. Every time that plugin needs to be downloaded, the user is asked for admin credentials at which point they call someone from the IT department to get them in. This isn't an issue for the most part, as most employees don't use the service regularly, but for the one who does, I'd like to figure out a way for her not to be prompted for admin credentials, but only when trying to work with WebEx.

Does anyone know of a good way to create an exception to bypass the need for admin credentials when installing specific software?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a run as admin shim, which can be put together with the MS application compatibility toolkit. Nearly all of the products I've worked with this was a pretty easy set up.

See [this technet blog article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2011/06/17/demystifying-shims-or-using-the-app-compat-toolkit-to-make-your-old-stuff-work-with-your-new-stuff.aspx) for details.